# Android ListView Swipe for Action like Twitter List

Tags: java, android, listview, twitter, swipe

I'm trying to implement the "swipe for action" feature - like you can see in the "new" twitter app. A closer description you find at [swipe for action description](http://www.androidpatterns.com/uap_pattern/swipe-for-action).

Now, are there any ideas/solution how to implement this feature?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Use a `GestureDetector` in each row, and wrap the row contents itself in a `ViewFlipper`. On a swipe, switch children of the `ViewFlipper`.

I have a [`ViewSwiper`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-viewswiper) that combines a `GestureDetector` and `ViewFlipper`, but it is designed to work in either direction (e.g., from the regular row, a swipe left *or* right would switch to the actions), which may or may not be desirable. But, it should give you an idea of how this might work.

Comment: Thanks for your response. 

I have found a similiar solution to yours. http://goo.gl/WpFEi
The first tests response a very good but laggy results. I think this solution needs a bit customizing - but i think it will work!

Thanks

Comment: @CodeDroid: Does *what* "work for Android 2.1+ GestureDetector"?

Answer (score 1):

I did something similiar to what you need - you can find some info about [there](http://software-workshop.eu/content/swiping-listview-elements). I'm doing some manual stuff there but it works nice. For your convenience here is the code I've used:

```
OnTouchListener gestureListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {

    private int padding = 0;
    private int initialx = 0;
    private int currentx = 0;
    private ViewHolder viewHolder;

    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            padding = 0;
            initialx = (int) event.getX();
            currentx = (int) event.getX();
            viewHolder = ((ViewHolder) v.getTag());
        }

        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
            currentx = (int) event.getX();
            padding = currentx - initialx;
        }

        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP ||
            event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL) {
            padding = 0;
            initialx = 0;
            currentx = 0;
        }

        if (viewHolder != null) {
            if (padding == 0) {
                v.setBackgroundColor(0xFF000000);
                if (viewHolder.running)
                    v.setBackgroundColor(0xFF058805);
            }
            if (padding > 75) {
                viewHolder.running = true;
                v.setBackgroundColor(0xFF00FF00);
                viewHolder.icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.clock_running);
            }
            if (padding < -75) {
                viewHolder.running = false;
                v.setBackgroundColor(0xFFFF0000);
            }
            v.setPadding(padding, 0, 0, 0);
        }
        return false;
    }
};
```